# What does this exception mean?

Tags: grails

I am getting this message while building my Grails app with MAVEN, After bootstrap is done I am getting this exception on my logs. Can someone direct me where to look for the cause of this exception? What does it trying to say ?

```
2012-09-26 13:00:45,532 [Thread-7] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanInAutowireByName(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBeanInAutowireByName(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory$autowireBeanProperties.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory$autowireBeanProperties.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.configureScaffoldingController(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$configureScaffoldingController.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.configureScaffolding(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2_closure10.doCall(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2_closure10.doCall(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-09-26 13:00:45,548 [Thread-7] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I'm seeing this error too, ever since adding a bootstrapping class that inserts some test data. Would love to know what I can do about this.

Comment: @stephan what version of Grails are you in ?

Comment: Not sure if its relavent, mine has gone not sure what fixed it though.  but couple questions do you have any scaffolded page? if so do they have test written for them ? is there any empty test ?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have scaffolded pages for most of my domain classes, and they all have stubbed unit tests. I'm planning to generate them and flesh out the tests later... it would be nice if that makes the error go away, but I'd still rather know what the actual cause is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having any source code or your version of `Grails`, just looking at your Exception stacktrace, the following stuck out:

```
Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

I did a bit of research into Grails JIRA and the following JIRA issue [GRAILS-8645](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8645) had the same stacktrace as you did.  Take a look at the stacktrace on this JIRA issue.  Per the JIRA issue, it appears to affect `Scaffolding` in 2.0 final, but is fixed with 2.0.1.

Comment: Thanks Philip, I'm using grails 2.1.0, this happens when maven finishes the bootstrap and starts the testing. I do use both static and dynamic scaffolding but not really sure what and why this happens at that phase. I would be more than happy to share my code but again not sure which part of my project might be causing it.